# In MathML, how to remove particular element based on its parent and its parent position?

Tags: xslt

Please help me to find the mmlmsubsup's third child starts with mmlmi with attribute.

Find the XML given below, suggest to remove the particular element based on its position and parent.

```
<article><mmlmath><mmlmsubsup><mmlmrow><mmlmi>A</mmlmi></mmlmrow><mmlmrow><mmlmi>b</mmlmi></mmlmrow><mmlmrow><mmlmi mathcolor="magenta">#</mmlmi><mmlmo>(</mmlmo><mmlmo>c</mmlmo><mmlmo>)</mmlmo></mmlmrow></mmlmsubsup></mmlmath></article>
```

SubSup.xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="mmlmsubsup">
    <mmlmsubsup>
            <xsl:for-each select="child::*[1]">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="child::*[1][name()='mmlmrow']">
                            <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:copy>
                        </xsl:when>

                        <xsl:otherwise><xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:copy></xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each>

            <xsl:for-each select="child::*[2]">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="child::*[1][name()='mmlmrow']">
                            <xsl:for-each select="mmlmrow">
                                <xsl:if test="child::*[1][name()='mmlmi'][@mathcolor]">delete</xsl:if>
                                <xsl:if test="not(child::*[name()='mmlmi'][@mathcolor])"><xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:copy></xsl:if>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                            <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:copy>
                        </xsl:when>

                        <xsl:otherwise><xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:copy></xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each>

            <xsl:for-each select="child::*[3]">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="child::*[1][name()='mmlmrow']">
                            <xsl:for-each select="mmlmrow">
                                <xsl:if test="child::*[1][name()='mmlmi'][@mathcolor]">delete</xsl:if>
                                <xsl:if test="not(child::*[name()='mmlmi'][@mathcolor])"><xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:copy></xsl:if>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                            <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:copy>
                        </xsl:when>

                        <xsl:otherwise><xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:copy></xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each>
    </mmlmsubsup>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Required OutPut:

Remove the "mmlmi" element of attribute "mathcolor", if mmlmi found as first child for second and third mmlmrow of mmlmsubsub ancetor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Remove the "mmlmi" element of attribute "mathcolor", if mmlmi found as
>   first child for second and third mmlmrow of mmlmsubsub ancetor.

I *think* that translates to:

```
<xsl:template match="mmlmi[@mathcolor]
                     [local-name(ancestor::mmlmsubsup/mmlmrow[2]/*[1])='mmlmi']
                     [local-name(ancestor::mmlmsubsup/mmlmrow[3]/*[1])='mmlmi']" />
```

It's hard to be sure because (1) the formulation is not quite clear, and (2) the source XML is not good testing material.

Comment: Hi Sir, Thanks a lot for your suggestion, I am getting required out put. We are working on MathML side, where we are inserting space before and after '(' and ')' thru perl program, later thru XSLT we are removing spaces, help of Xpath. Once again, Thanks a lot for your suggestion.